# VBA - found cases but with date

Tags: excel, vba, date

For the moment I use following code:

```
Sub Kalender2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim cl As Range
Dim found_cases As Byte
With ActiveSheet
    For Each cl In Application.Intersect(.Columns("E"), .UsedRange)
        If cl.Value = "Agent" Then
            cl.Offset(, -3).Value = "MONDAY " & found_cases + 1
            found_cases = found_cases + 1
        End If
    Next cl
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Now I want to the same but instead of "MONDAY" I want to use a date.

I have in column C the word Agent 6 times. Between these words I want to input a date, for example "04/01/2021". The next time the word "Agent" occurs it needs to be the next day that it inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will insert a date under every "Agent" encountered in column E.

```
Sub Kalender2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim cl As Range
Dim d As Date: d = DateSerial(2021, 1, 1)
With ActiveSheet
    For Each cl In Application.Intersect(.Columns("E"), .UsedRange)
        If cl.Value = "Agent" Then
            cl.Offset(1) = d
            d = d + 1
        End If
    Next cl
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```